# Load ONLY the JKS in Java to call URL

Tags: java, certificate, jks

I have a JKS with this information:

[image]

Importing this JKS in SOAP UI, I can call the remotes URLs without problem.

OK, but I want to do the same in Java (only with the JKS), with this instruction:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","C:\\myJKS.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "myPassword");
```

The error is:

```
the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
```

**My idea is work like SOAP UI, only load or import the JKS and no more.**

PD: I've imported in the JKS the cert:

[image]

And the error was:

```
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```